# Golang Welcome Tour: How to run tour (package tour is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/tour))?

Tags: go

I'm trying to run the go `tour` program the first time following this [welcome documentation](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/3).

I've run the next command:

```
go install golang.org/x/website/tour@latest
```

But when I'm trying to run
`go run tour`
I get the next exception:

```
package tour is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/tour)
```

And I haven't found any additional docs of how to run the `tour` program.

How to run the `tour` program correctly?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go run tour` is not the correct command.

From your link,

> "This will place a tour binary in your GOPATH's bin directory"

You need to find your GOPATH's bin directory, make sure it's in your $PATH (or specify absolute or relative path including that directory).

Your go bin directory may well be `~/go/bin`; mine is.

The executable you'll run is `tour`, not `go ...`. So maybe `~/go/bin/tour` will work for you.

Keep in mind that unlike Java, Go executables don't require a VM and so they're invoked directly.

Comment: maybe also good to add that to the PATH variable.

Comment: I second that suggestion.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path looks like `~/go/bin` is a valid path element even

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely right. I missed that it's already executable.